# Add two number variables from two different ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ecmascript-5

I want to add two numbers and calculate the total from two different ajax calls, so that I can append the total value to a dom

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("MonthlyReport")",
            data: { id: id },
              success: function (data) {
                  var total = 0;
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


             // Create our number formatter.
                total += data[i].interestAmountPerMonth 

               }

                  var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                      style: 'currency',
                      currency: 'USD',
                  });

                  const totalAmountAccrued = formatter.format(total)
                  $('#totalAmountAccrued').append(totalAmountAccrued)

            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {}
          });
```

The second ajax is below

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetAllLoan")",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (result) {

                var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
                    style: 'currency',
                    currency: 'USD',
                });

                const originalLoanAmount = formatter.format(result.originalLoanAmount);
                const amountWrittenOff = formatter.format(result.amountWrittenOff);
                

            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
            }
        });
```

I want to achieve something like this **let overallTotal =  totalAmountAccrued +  amountWrittenOff**

Comment: What seems to be the problem? You can just add the two values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.when to combine multiple requests
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 0):

Declare  totalAmountAccrued and amountWrittenOff with **let** above the ajax call.

like let totalAmountAccrued;

Remove const from `const totalAmountAccrued` and `const amountWrittenOff`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Promise.all` which triggers `then` when all promises are resolved

```
function makeFetch(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({url: url, data: data})
}

Promise.all([
    makeFetch('@Url.Action("MonthlyReport")', {id: id}),
    makeFetch('@Url.Action("GetAllLoan")', {id: id})
])
.then(([monthlyReport, allLoan]) => {
    const totalAmountAccrued = monthlyReport.reduce((sum, data) => sum + data.interestAmountPerMonth, 0)
    const amountWrittenOff = allLoan.amountWrittenOff
    const overallTotal = totalAmountAccrued + amountWrittenOff
})
```